# Removing facet's strip in ggplot2 plot results in error "Figure margins too large"

Tags: r, ggplot2, pycharm

When I try to remove the strips of a facet plot, e.g. with

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
   geom_point(aes(x=drat, y=mpg, color=cyl)) +
   geom_line(aes(x=drat, y=mpg, color=cyl)) +
   facet_grid(vs~am) +
   theme(strip.text.y = element_blank(),
         strip.background.y = element_blank()
   )
```

I get the error message

> Figure margins too large

with ggplot version 3.3.3, when I am running this in PyCharm. When I run it in RStudio, the issue does not arise.

Why is that and what can I do about it?

Comment: Is this done on `Rstudio` as I couldn't reproduce on R console.  Then, you may need to make the plot window a bit larger

Comment: @akrun: It is done in PyCharm actually. I checked: The issue does not arise in RStudio. I did not even consider that it might be an issue related to PyCharm. I will update the question.

Comment: Can you try to make the plot window larger (if there is an option)

Comment: @akrun: There is an option to choose between "IDE" and "R" - whatever that means. I switched from "IDE" to "R" and now the plot is displayed. Thanks for sparring!